# Generic function

Tags: c#, generics, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to create a simple generic function:

```
    public T GetPost<T>(HttpListenerRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        Stream body = request.InputStream;
        Encoding encoding = request.ContentEncoding;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(body, encoding);

        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        body.Close();
        reader.Close();

        // NullRefferenceException on this line:
        typeof(T).GetField("Name").SetValue(null, "djasldj");


        return //yet to come
    }
```

Strangely the line with `typeof(T)` return this error:

> `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

[What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Also how can I return the constructed T class?

This is how I call the function:

```
 string data = GetPost<User>(ctx.Request);
```

And this is the `User` class:

```
public static string Name { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling this method?

Comment: `GetField("Name")` is returning `null`, not `typeof(T)`. That means `T` does not have a public field called `Name`.

Comment: @StijnBernards: this is a *runtime error* or a *compiler error*?

Comment: @Lee I know I said typeof(T) to indicate what line

Comment: @StijnBernards: in that case the `Name` field should be static. Can you provide the class definition of your `T`?

Comment: @StijnBernards: I think that's a property and not a field.

Comment: @CommuSoft ah. Yes. stupid accident

Comment: First question is duplicate of 2 ("What is NRE" and "Get Property via reflection"). If you still need answer to second one please make sure to add separate question for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you look for a field, but your `T` has an automatic property.

You thus need to call:

```
typeof(T).GetProperty("Name").SetValue(null, "djasldj");
```

This code for instance (stripped unnecessary code) works:

```
class Foo {

    public static string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo.Name);
        GetPost<Foo>();
        Console.WriteLine(Foo.Name);
    }

    public static void GetPost<T>() where T : new() {
        typeof(T).GetProperty("Name").SetValue(null, "djasldj");
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know it's possible!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're trying to set property of T. But T is only a type you pass to the generic method. You've constrained it with new(), so as far as I know T type should provide parameterless constructor.

Let's say you call it `GetPost<User>(request);`

It should return user with some properties set. Take a look on that example (User class is as you wrote)...

This is a class with generic method:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Class1
    {
        public T GetPost<T>(string s) where T : new()
        {
            if (typeof(T)== typeof(User))
            {
                var result = new User();
                result.Password = "some";
                return (T)(object)result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is usage

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c = new Class1();
            var obj = c.GetPost<User>("dsjkd");
        }
    }
}
```

After execution variable "obj" is User object with password field set.

EDIT:

I've just seen CommuSoft post. It's better solution I think, but I'm not deleting my answer, maybe someone will find it useful.

Comment: But the compiler _does_ know the explicit type that T is at compile time.  `GetPost<string>` the type is `string`, which is a hard-coded value known at compile time.

Comment: In contrast to common belief, if one uses generics, the type **is** known at compile type. You can define a method with `<T>` but for each use, that `T` is initialized. That's why Java's wildcards `?` are not supported.

Comment: Thank you. I was wrong. I'm sorry.